# Alpha Testing Link at Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, beta-testing

Where is my account Alpha testing link for testers? I waited 48 hours upto now so what is actual place for link?

[image]

Play store changed all layout now so I am asking this question.
Also I have gone through all places in Play Store account but found nothing. Just because of new layout I was facing this problem otherwise I loaded apps multiple time in Alpha and Beta testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, you could try something like this, it worked for my BETA tests. ( I am not sure if it works with alpha)

```
https://play.google.com/apps/testing/YOUR_APP_PACKAGE
```

Comment: really thanks for this reply, I tried but can't able to found a link to be a tester at Play Store account.